# Gnu Make's recursiveness and friends

Tags: c++, recursion, makefile, gnu

Maybe I'm doing something wrong but *make* refuses to check the timestamps of the dependencies when the makefile looks like this.

```
# This makefile won't update the objects if you modify the .cpp files
# and it will only create them if they do not exist.
CC=g++
FL=-g
OBJECTD=../obj
SOURCED=../src

# Get all .cpp files in ../src
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)

# Convert .cpp to .o then add ../obj in front
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(OBJECTD)/,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES)))

# You sir must execute yourself whether you like it or not
.PHONY:all

all:$(OBJECTS)
    @echo : Leaving `src`


# This wont work as expected ...
# @echo : Compiling $(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@))
# echoes Compiling logger.cpp
# But $(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@)) will not be parsed
# correctly
$(OBJECTS):$(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@))
    @echo : Compiling $(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@))
    @$(CC) $(FL) -c $(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@)) -o $@
```

I believe it just won't accept  `$(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@))`

even though the docs state that

> *In a pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern Rules), ‘$@’ is the name of whichever target caused the rule's
>   recipe to be run.*

Doing the compilation for each file seperately, works fine.
For instance:

```
../obj/logger.o:logger.cpp
    @echo : Compiling $<
    @$(CC) $(FL) -c $< -o $@
```

+------------+
: **eXtra nfo**:
+------------+

What I'm trying to achieve is to read the sources from the currect directory, check if they're changed if they're, proceed to compiling them whilst placing the objects at ../obj instead of the current directory.
This is the makefile located in ../src , there is also another one for linking in the parent directory.

Graphical representation of the structure I want work on

```
 +--- Parent Directory ------+
 |        |        |         |
 |        |        |         |
bin      obj      inc       src
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule:

```
$(OBJECTS):$(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@))
    ...
```

doesn't work because `$@` has no value in the prerequisite list. From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

> [Automatic variables] cannot be accessed directly within the prerequisite list of a
>   rule.

Try [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJECTD)/%.o : %.cpp
    @echo : Compiling $<
    @$(CC) $(FL) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: there are three new ideas here: 1) `$@` doesn't work in the prerequisite list, 2) static pattern rules, and 3) `$<` means the first prerequisite. Which one is giving you trouble?

Comment: I get the $< part. The one I do not get is the nested targets.

Comment: Follow the link ("this") to learn about static pattern rules.

Comment: Reading: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage, thanks alot :P